# What is meant by "Single Driver Per channel"? SATA

Tags: hard-drive, sata

In the following context SATA only supports a single driver per channel?

What is a channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A channel in this context is a single electrical connection. SCSI of old connected multiple devices to a channel and addressed each device through a feature in the signaling protocol on the wires. SATA lacks this as it is purposely a simpler protocol.

Which begs the question, *So how to port-multipliers work, then?*

This is an optional extension to the SATA protocol that not all controllers implement (it adds cost). When used with a port-multiplier you can actually connect multiple drives to a single channel, as the port-multiplier handles the drive-addressibility.

Comment: Thank you for your help it is appreciated. By single electrical connection would this mean one cable from the drive to the motherboard in the server/PC? Very new to this

Comment: @topcat Yep, that's exactly it, one cable.